# C# dotnetcore Regex Hangs When Given Long, Unbroken String

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core

I have a regex that is hanging when it tries to match against a long, unbroken string. Here is a sample console app:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Stopwatch sw;
        string pattern = @"(?:(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?";
        string input = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to match regex.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("Starting regex...");

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        sw.Stop();


        Console.WriteLine($"Regex completed in {sw.Elapsed}. Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The Regex is meant to find URLs in user-generated comments. When a normal comment is provided, it processes in no time at all. A 100-word lorem ipsum it processes in about 36ms. As soon as a long, unbroken string is introduced, the regex hangs and, as far as I can tell, never finishes processing. The string does not need to have the same characters repeated.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: That sounds very much like your regex pattern is suffering from catastrophic backtracking. Also, your regex pattern is so long, complicated and essentially unreadable, i hope no one else will have to maintain it later ;-)

Comment: Besides long regex the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is also causing the problem. Without ignore case flag it will proceed normally.

Comment: @MikeKaskun, yeah, alright. Now, replace the given input sample string with `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"`. What now?

Comment: Yea, the guy needs to fix his regex :D

Comment: @elgonzo Yes, I didn't get to choose the Regex. If I can't figure out how to get it to work, I may have evidence to use a simpler one.

Comment: So probably too many optional clauses, that's the working theory. I'll try tweaking it.

Comment: I feel with you. I refuse to pick that regex apart, i am not enough of a masochist to do that voluntarily. :-(  I would suggest instead of using such a complex regex, try to develop several different regex patterns that each match only a certain kind/style of URL. If you got those regex(es) working, you might think of combining them into one regex, using an alternation. But personally, i would prefer to keep regex simple, readable, maintainable, even if it would mean that i would have to deal with more than just a single regex...

Comment: Things like `(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*` kill the performance. Search for quantified groups with one obligatory and other optional patterns inside. Replace so that each subsequent pattern could not match the same char/type of chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with your regex is that there are optional patterns alongside obligatory one pattern inside a `*` / `+` quantified group, see `(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*`. This may lead (with long non-matching strings) to the the behavior when the regex engine starts trying all possible routes to match a string, and there may appear too many of them, so many that the system appears to freeze: a catastrophic backtracking.

Thus, if you plan to use your simplified solution you should avoid the similar patterns, use

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:-\.)?[^\s/?.#-]+(?:\.[^\s/?.#-]+)*(?:/\S*)?
```

where `(?:[^\s/?\.#-]+\.?)+` is unrolled as `[^\s/?.#-]+(?:\.[^\s/?.#-]+)*`. While it is longer, the engine fails much quicker than when the optional pattern is inside the quantified group.

If you want to fix the original pattern, use

```
string pattern = @"(?:(?:http|ftp)s?://)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!1(?:0|27)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!1(?:69\.254|92\.168|72\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1]))(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+(?:-[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*)(?:\.[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+(?:-[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*)*(?:\.[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/\S*)?";
```

Check how [this regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/Iah08U/1) and how `(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*` is unrolled as `[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+(?:-[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*` to match patterns so that each subsequent pattern could not match the same chars. I also merged some negative lookaheads with common "suffixes". Note that `(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?` is left untouched as it may need to match any `:`s up to the last `:` before the rest of matching patterns.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I ran your regex's in my sample program and they worked beautifully. While the answer I posted works as well, yours are much more performant and allows me to use the better matching regex.